# How To Reduce Nested Query Time using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**How Can i reduce this query run time with any type of join or sub-query or nested query.**

```
select 
`p`.`id`,
`p`.`name`,
SUM(s.quantity) as inst,
from `product` as `p` 
LEFT JOIN  sales as s ON s.pid=p.`id` AND s.sales_id IN (SELECT invoice.invoice_id FROM invoice WHERE invoice.ccid NOT IN (SELECT ccid FROM ticket WHERE st='1'))
where `p`.`hc` = '1' 
GROUP BY `p`.`id` 
order by `p`.`name` DESC
```

Comment: use inner join instead on in query and left join instead of not in .....that will reduce query time because in query take much time

Comment: `select 
p.id,
p.name AS name,
SUM(ss.instock) as inst
from product as p
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT s.id,s.pid,CASE COUNT(crt.salvage_part) WHEN 1 THEN 0 
ELSE s.quantity END AS instock
FROM sales as s 
LEFT JOIN invoice as i ON i.invoice_id=s.sales_id
LEFT JOIN crt ON crt.cc_id=i.cc_id AND crt.st='1'
GROUP BY s.id) as ss ON ss.pid=p.id
where p.hc = '1' 
GROUP BY p.id 
order by p.name DESC`        **Tried This Too, But Can't Reduce it's runtime.**

Comment: The question is nonsensical as, clearly, this query would produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i come to a solution & it works**

```
select 
s.pid,
SUM(s.quantity) AS squan 
from invoice as i 
LEFT JOIN sales as s ON s.sales_id=i.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN crt ON crt.cc_id=i.cc_id AND crt.ch='0'
WHERE 
crt.ch='0' 
AND 
(i.cc_id!='' OR i.cc_id!='0') 
GROUP BY i.invoice_id
```

Comment: You SELECT pid, but GROUP BY invoice_id. This is liable to provide an indeterminate/erroneous result.

Answer (score 1):

Add index on st from ticket and also add index on ccid from invoice and sales_id from sales.

Try using Explain clause before your query whether created index is being used or not in possible_keys column output .

Comment: Please explain what you mean. with example if possible.

Comment: Not Working using index